# Expectation of the exponential of the amount of time a Brownian motion spent in half space

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $(B)_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Can we calculate the expectation of the exponential of the time $B$ will be spent above $c$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left\{\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{B_u>c\}}du\right\}\right]?$$

My thought is: Let $L_t:=\exp\left\{\int_0^t\mathbb{1}_{\{B_u>c\}}du\right\}$, it is a non-decreasing process, hence, a sub-martingale. Next step is to identify its Doob-Meyer decomposition, and this is where I cannot proceed.

Comment: Borodin, Salminen, P. 128, formula 1.4.3.

Comment: From the answer by user zhoraster, the result is given by formula 1.4.3 Borodin and Salminen.